# Finding rows with specific words in an excel sheet

Tags: python, r, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table similar to this format:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi77F.png)

My table has 50000 rows and 800 columns, certain cells (tab-separated) contain multiple comma-separated words (e.g L,N). I want to retain only rows that contain one of a set of words (say A to N) at a given column (say col2) and remove the remaining rows.

Is it possible to do using Vlookup or there is another way to do it? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious: why did you tag this with [r] and [python]? Are you interested in solutions that use those? You don't say so in your post.

Comment: "A to N" indicates a range of several words which isn't "one of a set of words". Please modify your question to clarify.

Comment: @Aron If the solution to my problem can be offered by [r] and [python], I would like to try them.

Comment: Where/what exactly is your "table"?  you say tab-separated so is it a text file you have?

Comment: @Tim Yes, it is a .txt file. But certain fields/cells contain multiple comma-separated words.

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper column, perhaps on the extreme right of a copy of your worksheet. Enter this formula in row 2 of that column. Modify the formula to replace column C with the ID of the helper column (the one in which you write the formula) and replace B with the column in which to find the word. Cope the formula all the way down.

```
=ISERROR(FIND(C$1,$B2))
```

Now enter the word you want to keep in cell(1) of the helper column (C$1 in my example). The column will fill with TRUE and FALSE.

- TRUE means that the word wasn't found and the row should be deleted
- FALSE means that the word exists and should be kept

Now sort the sheet on that column and delete the block with TRUE in it. 15 seconds flat, after you have done it for a few times. That's faster than any VBA or r or Python solution could be made to run.

Comment: Thank you for replying Variatus! This works pretty fast for one query. However, I have ~5000 such words to search for. Please let me know if I have to do it by creating 5000 helper columns or there is any easier way. Sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: Even if you had code that prepares 5000 workbooks for you in, say, an hour - instead of 24 as my suggestion would - how long would it take you to look at your newly created 5000 files? Speed without direction is rather useless. But, let's face it, we are now into whether or not I shall write the code for you. I don't work for free and I don't work for money (not that you offered any, either) and I don't believe in your project. Therefore the answer is no. Good luck.

Comment: I am a beginner and looking for directions to learn something which I don't know but I have not asked anyone to write a piece of code for me. Rather, I want to learn and write it myself. Thank you.

Comment: Publish here what you tried. That's the forum requirement, in fact. People here will help you when you get stuck.

Comment: Are you still needing a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue I had was in communicating conveying what I did, how and why. No need to, so deleted.

So, Select any part, section or range of your table and run the code.

You can remove the section of the code below 'clear any existng fiters' if you dont need to delete the found data and want to keep in your sheet, still tagged for additional purposes (like you could copy those bits to another file if you want, etc).

The code below should do what you asked in your question, and leave you with just the parts of the table that DONT contain, in your selection, any of your terms. i.e. it will delete and move up rows in your table according to your criteria.

& yes Python & R can simply do this for you too too, with dataframes in python, with less code. But this VBA code worked for my many examples. Don't know how it will fare with 50000 rows and X columns, but it should be alright {*Post edit:* **It works fine**}.

```
    Sub SearchTableorSelectionDeletetermsFound5()
    

    Dim corresspondingpartner() As Variant
 
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Selection
    Dim col As Range
    For Each col In rng.Columns

    Dim r As Range
    Dim rn As Variant
    Dim Rownum As Long
    
    Rownum = Selection.Rows.Count
    
    ReDim rm(0 To Rownum) As Variant 'size of this array needs to equal or bigger than your selection
                  
    'With Sheet2
    terms = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

    k = 1
    For rw = 0 To UBound(terms)
    ReDim Preserve corresspondingpartner(rw)
    corresspondingpartner(rw) = (k / k) 'gives each correspondong partner element an id of 1.
    k = k + 1

   Next
   'End With
    
   For Each r In Selection
   n = 0
   m = n
 
   For Each c In terms
   ' Checks for each term in turn in the terms column.
   ' If it finds one, it inserts the corresponding corresspondingpartner name in the column cell/corresponding row column O (*post edit: now, column ADU)*
   If r.Offset(0, 0).Value Like "*" & c & "*" Then

    
   rm(n) = corresspondingpartner(n) 'corresspondingpartner(n)  and in the end, you dont even need this, you can replace with any value which the auto fiter section looks for to delete
    'so you can  remove any instances and classees of corresspondingpartner, including the making of this corresponding second array
    'turns out it could have been just if =1

    Cells(r.Row, 801).Value = rm(n) / rm(n) 'Sheets("HXY2").
    '##### YOU DONT EVEN NEED A HLOOKUP! :)
    '#### BUT I STILL WANT TO GET RID OF THE OFFSET COLUMS, DO IT WITHOUT THEM. DONE!! :)
    '''###''' same here , turns out could have just been =1
    
    End If
    n = n + 1
    Next
    Next
    
    Next col


  
  'Clear any existing filters
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

  '1. Apply Filter
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1:ADU5000").AutoFilter Field:=801, Criteria1:=corresspondingpartner(n) / corresspondingpartner(n)
  
  '2. Delete Rows
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:ADU5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
  '3. Clear Filter
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

You might be able to see that in the beginning I was working with to print offset column results, from the table/selection -  which took up unneccisary space and also was employing a VBA `Application.WorksheetFunction.Hlookup`  in the code to give a final result column, tagging the rows to delete, but that was in the end unneccissary.  Those earlier versions/macros worked too, but were slower, so I did it without the need for helper columns, using arrays.

I turned to my friend, [excel campus - delete rows based on conditions][1] to embed and tweak the autoflter code at the end which deletes the rows you don't want , so you don't have to do it yourself)

Its now a "virtual" hlookup on the array matches in your selection (or data), by deleting all rows that match your specifications/requirements leaving you with the data you want.

I know and have a huge hunch it could be further improved, expanded  streamlined much further (starting with the way I produce the arrays), but I'm happy with its functionality and potential scope for now.

[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwNcSZrzd_w&t=6s)

Comment: Actually, as the only instance these words are marked as found (apart from in col 2 in your ask) are in the 15th column (in my code , or if you change 15 to any other number , then that column number), the auto filter only needs to filter by that column and not any others , to be able to select the relevent rows and delete them. So you don't have to change the autofilter range to anything else, unless the range/column you choose for the output tags is beyond column AZ.   N.B. =column(any cell in the column) gives you the column number.

Comment: No it's not slow. It works over 800 columns deep 5000 rows long. Just tested it. In your case your going to have to change my code to a1:adu and the 15 to 800. I'll do that in the reply.